# How do you pull variable from an object in a linked list of objects

Tags: java, linked-list

I am currently building an address book.  I am storing each entry into the address book as an object.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to get any specific variable from an object and display it.  Such as the firstName for example.  It's supposed to write the variables to a file which will be loaded into the array when the program is started again.

```
        class ExitListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(FILE);
            ListIterator it1 = set.listIterator();
            while (it1.hasNext()){


            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `set`?? What is its type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to have to apply my psychic debugging powers here, as you haven't presented any code. My guess is that you've got a variable like this:

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.add(new Person());
...
Object fetched = list.getFirst();
// Problems...
```

If you use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), this becomes:

```
// Or use an interface type, of course
LinkedList<Person> list = new LinkedList<Person>();
list.add(new Person());
...
Person fetched = list.getFirst();
System.out.println(person.getFirstName()); // Hooray!
```

Comment: I got it figured out from your second block of code.  Thank you for your assistance.  I wasn't doing the Person fetched = list.getFirst();

Answer (score 0):

If you mean LinkedList then you can simply loop thru your linkedlist and get the first name .

```
LinkedList<Person> list = new LinkedList<Person>();
Person p = new Person();
p.setFirstName("myname");
list.add(p);

for(Person p: list) {
  Sysout(p.getFirstName());
}
```

Comment: @RohitJain now, my code would compile with java6 .. check my edit